# "Single Sign on" using OKTA in an MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, okta, okta-api

I need to implement the "Single Sign on" using OKTA in an MVC Application. I have created an account on Okta and created an application.

I can able to get the details such as Identity Provider Single Sign-On URL,Identity Provider Issuer and X.509 Certificate from OKTA.

But I am not able to configure it in to the MVC site.

Does any body know how can I configure "Single Sign on" using OKTA in an MVC Application?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend taking a look at the sample applications available on [github.com/oktadeveloper](https://github.com/oktadeveloper/).

For SSO, this [ASP.NET project](https://github.com/oktadeveloper/okta-oauth-aspnet-codeflow) is a great example using [OpenID Connect](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/oidc.html) to walk you through this process.

Answer (score 0):

We're currently adopting Okta, and chose to use SAML. I found the info at [Okta Blog](http://developer.okta.com/blog/2016/03/22/use-kentor-authservices-with-okta) very helpful. In this Blog they reference a module by Kentor IT, which makes implementing SAML really easy.

Keep in mind, the currentversion is 0.20, so you might have to tweak a little.

- .Net version should be 4.6.2, or you have to go to SHA1 encryption instead of SHA256
- We had to handle the way Okta gives back groups, where we needed roles (hint: Within 'Group Attribute Statements' set Name to 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role' and Name format to URI. This way groups will be added as Role claim to the SAML token

Happy Okta'ing

Gerwin

Comment: Please, could you insert the referenced information in your answer?

Comment: Use [this](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices/blob/master/README.md) link to get to the Kentor module